# finish Activity using context

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-context

I had this issue, I don't understand why it's not finishing the activity :

```
      if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {

        Timber.e("==> logout is running");

        Intent i = new Intent(activity, SplashActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(i);
            ((MainActivity) activity).finish(); // this cast to have finish method
}
```

I check the logcat , I found

> "==> logout is running"

but nothing happend, the app still there.

Answer (score 0):

I debug few minutes then, I found that finish works only with **FragmentActivity** not **MainActivity** (I don't know Why).

but the solution for me is :

```
 ((FragmentActivity) activity).finish();
```